# ResultSet to Android Cursor

Tags: android, jdbc, cursor

I my connecting to a MySQL database that is on PC from my android application.

I am using java.sql.jdb for that. Now I want my result set to get in android.database.cursor??

How can I do that..??
Thats my code I am using in android application its getting the results for database but can't cast to Cursor:

```
    Connection connect = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    Statement statement = null;

    try {
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+DbHelper.DB_Path+"/"+DbHelper.DB_Name+"?"
                + "user="+ DbHelper.DB_UserName+ "&password="+ DbHelper.DB_Pass);


        statement = connect.createStatement();
        // Result set get the result of the SQL query
        resultSet = statement
                .executeQuery("Select * from btag_store "+
                        "Where "+
                        "guid='"+filterArgs+"'");


        }
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Cursor cc;
    cc = (Cursor) resultSet; // error in type casr
```

I know that type casting will give me error, but is there any other way for that..??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply, you cannot. Unless you are willing to do all the work to define an object that implements the `Cursor` interface and uses a `ResultSet` to fulfil `Cursor`'s implementation details. That would be somewhat silly, though, as the `ResultSet` object is already designed to iterate over results returned from the database. The cleanest approach is to use the `ResultSet` object as it was intended.

Answer (score 0):

What Dave said is correct. My database items were constructed upon Cursor (Sqlite) but I need the same entrypoint wiht MySQL. So I tried this:

I created a base class
**AbstractCursorGen.java**:

```
import android.database.Cursor;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

public abstract class AbstractCursorGen {
    protected Cursor c;
    protected ResultSet rs;
    public abstract int getColumnIndex(String iName);
    public abstract String getString(String iName);
    public abstract int getInt(String iName);
    public abstract long getLong(String iName);
    public abstract boolean moveToNext();
    public abstract void close();
}
```

Then the one using Cursor will hold the instance of cursor. There is an additional benefit by getting result giving directly the column string. My code uses this for SQLite.

**CursonGen.Java**:

```
import android.database.Cursor;

public class CursorGen extends AbstractCursorGen{
    public CursorGen(Cursor c)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public int getColumnIndex(String iName)
    {
        return c.getColumnIndex(iName);
    }


    public String getString(String iName){
        return c.getString(getColumnIndex(iName));
    }

    public int getInt(String iName){
        return c.getInt(getColumnIndex(iName));
    }
    public long getLong(String iName){
        return c.getLong(getColumnIndex(iName));
    }

    public boolean moveToNext()
    {
        return c.moveToNext();
    }

    public void close()
    {
        c.close();
    }
}
```

And one built upon the resultset. This is used for MySQL results

**ResultSetGen.java**

```
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ResultSetGen extends AbstractCursorGen{
    public ResultSetGen(ResultSet rs)
    {
        this.rs = rs;
    }

    public int getColumnIndex(String iName)
    {
        try {
            return rs.findColumn(iName);
        } catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Log.e("PROX","Column not found");
            return -1;
        }
    }


    public String getString(String iName){
        try {
            return rs.getString(getColumnIndex(iName));
        } catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Log.e("PROX","Column not found");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public int getInt(String iName){
        try {
            return rs.getInt(getColumnIndex(iName));
        } catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Log.e("PROX","Column not found");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    public long getLong(String iName){
        try {
            return rs.getLong(getColumnIndex(iName));
        } catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Log.e("PROX","Column not found");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public boolean moveToNext()
    {
        try {
            return rs.next();
        } catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Log.e("PROX","Column not found");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void close()
    {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Log.e("PROX","Column not found");
        }
    }
}
```

The trick is providing implementation only for the methods I'm actually using.

This is finally called by (one example)

```
public Person(AbstractCursorGen cursor)
    {
       setFromCursor(cursor);
    }

    protected void setFromCursor(AbstractCursorGen cursor)
    {
        PersonID        = cursor.getLong    (   COLUMN_PERSON_ID);
        ClusterID       = cursor.getInt     (   COLUMN_CLUSTER_ID);
        Name            = cursor.getString  (   COLUMN_NAME);
        .....
    }
```

Hope this helps.